# Styling specific list within UL

Tags: html, css

Say this is my setup:

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#">Any distance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">10 km</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">30 km</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">50 km</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my css how can I style my list depending on what UL it is in? I tried this:

```
#filters ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

But I didn't have any luck, the same with several different variations on this. I know it's a basic question but I'm still learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect for what you are trying to achieve:

```
#filters ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

`#filters ul li` will select `li` elements that are descendants of a `ul` that is a descendant of an element with `id="filters"`.

You want:

```
#filters li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply want:

```
#filters li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The reason it doesn't work at the moment is because it's saying the `ul` INSIDE an element with the ID `#filters`. (e.g. `<div id="filters"><ul>...`)

Another correct way of styling your list would be `ul#filters li`. This says that you want a `ul` element with the ID "filters". This is unnecessary though, since you can only have one element with the ID "filters".

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong.

Below are some alternative selectors that will work just fine:

```
ul#filters li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The above selector will apply to the LI elements of any UL element that has the ID 'filter'. This selector has the highest specificity (in the given context). Here's a good article on specificity http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

```
#filters li {
     padding: 10px;
}
```

The above selector will apply to the LI elements of an element that has the ID 'filter'.

```
#filters * {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The above selector will apply to ANY element of an element that has an ID 'filter'. I don't advise you to use this, but you could because a UL element has to be followed by LI elements according to the W3C.

Answer (score 0):

The `#filters` is the `ul` itself, you must select the children like this:

```
ul#filters li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

However, because ID is unique, you can ommit the `ul`:

```
#filters li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
#filters li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It would need to be

`ul#filters li{some code}`

You put the id or class after the name of the element.

or simply

`#filters li{your code}`

Comment: Make sure there is no space btw ul and #filters because this is basically calling a unordered list with id "filters".

Comment: Kevin's is also right if you want to style just the individual li items.